# Page refresh based on tab switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, session

In my explorer, I have some tabs/pages opened. I can change some global informations on those tabs/pages like a session var.
If I am on a page/tab, I change this session var and I switch back to another tab, how can I refresh my actual page to display to right text based on my modified session var ?

Are there some events ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Are you using frames? Then you can refresh the frame using target.

Comment: I think you should be more precise in this question. What do you exactly plan to do for the user navigating through your site?
I don't think it would be very user-friendly to refresh some of his explorer tabs without asking, and also, I'm not even sure it's possible to do this kind of things on his other opened tabs. As mentioned by asifsid88, you could use the $(window).focus listener, but I don't think that will fit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery it's possible you need to catch the window focus event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).focus(function() {
      //Your logic here . . . (Refresh the content)
    });
});
```